# Derivation of conditional probability density formula for a random variable smaller than a number?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am trying to find a formula for the conditional probability density below:

> $f_X(x| X < M)$

where $M$ is a constant and $X$ is a continuous random variable.

I want to relate the formula of the conditional probability density with the probability distribution of $X$ (whether it is density function $f_X(x)$ or cumulative function $F_X(x)$). But I can't do that, could you please suggest me a solution ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x < M$ you have $f_X(x)=f_X(x\mid X < M) \,\mathbb P(X <M)$, so

$$f_X(x\mid X < M) =\dfrac{f_X(x)}{\mathbb P(X <M)} \text{ if } x <M$$ and $0$ otherwise.

If $X$ has a continuous distribution then $\mathbb P(X <M) = F_X(M) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^M f_X(x) \, dx$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Can you please explain why we have the first equation ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge In a sense it is a natural application of conditional probability, but you could say if $x < M$ then $\mathbb P(X \le x)=\mathbb P(X \le x \mid X < M)  \,\mathbb P(X <M)$, i.e. $F_X(x)=F_{X\mid X<M}(x \mid X < M)  \,\mathbb P(X <M)$, so taking the derivative with respect to $x$ gives  $F_X'(x)=F_{X\mid X<M}'(x \mid X < M)  \,\mathbb P(X <M)$, i.e. $f_X(x)=f_{X\mid X<M}(x \mid X < M)  \,\mathbb P(X <M)$